# Updating properties of a subclassed UIButton via UserDefault settings

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults, subclass

I have subclassed a UIButton to use throughout my project. These UIButton subclasses will have a border color that changes based on what the user selects in the settings. The setting is saved with UserDefaults.

**Problem:**
When I load up the App for the first time, the button border is the correct color - however, when I change settings (to ultimately change the button border) - nothing happens. The buttons only change color once I close out of the App and re-open.

**My code**

```
class CustomSeasonButton: UIButton {
var seasonCold = Bool()
let nsDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "themeChanged"))

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // ...
        self.seasonCold = nsDefaults.bool(forKey: "savedSeasonDefault")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshButtonBorder), name: notification.name, object: nil)

        refreshButtonBorder()
    }

func refreshButtonBorder() {
    print("Notification Received")
    if seasonCold {
       seasonCold = false
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    else {
       seasonCold = true
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
    }
}


}
```

**Settings**

```
class SettingsVC: UITableViewController {
//...
    var notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "themeChanged"))
//...
}
```

*And then in the IBAction of the season select - I have the following:*

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```

So as you may see from my code above, the button border color *should* be switching between Blue and Red, depending on what's selected with the UserDefaults.

The only way I can get the border color to change is if I close the App and reopen it.

**Question:**
How can I make sure the UIButton subclasses get a border color change every time the settings (UserDefaults) is updated? Thanks!

Comment: You want to change existing buttons when the setting changes?

Comment: @rmaddy - Precisely! Users can change a Seasons setting within the settings view. Depending on what season gets selected, the border color of other (subclassed) UIButtons should change accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seasonCold = false {
   didSet {
      refreshButtonBorder()
   }
}


func refreshButtonBorder() {
    if seasonCold {
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    else {
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

and set seasonCold whenever you change userdefaults "savedSeasonDefault"

for one to many calls use NotificationCenter, every instance of the subclassed button should have a NotificationObserver, and post the notification whenever UserDefaults changes

```
var notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "seasonChanged"))
```

in awake from nib or your init function

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshButtonBorder), name: notification.name, object: nil)
```

whenever season cold changes sprinkle notification dust

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```

Comment: But the hard part is what you left out of the answer - updating `seasonCold` for every existing `UIButton` when the setting changes.

Comment: Edited to include that ^

Comment: @Gaston Gonzalez - Thanks for your help here. It's been way too long since I've worked with NSNotificationCenter so i'm a bit rusty here. I've edited my original post. "Notifcation Received" is printing (albeit printing 9 times each time i change buttons!) - However, the borders still aren't changing. Any tips are appreciated

Comment: You're never actually changing season cold ;), try switching it to false in the selector function

Comment: What is "it" referring to in "switching it to false" ? I'm switching season settings (true / false) via IBOutlet in the settings view before calling 'NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)' - Is that what you mean?

Comment: a ha! I got it. The property observer wasn't needed in my case. In refreshButtonBorder, I just needed to do what you said - update if the bool is true or false! That did the trick. Also - the observer was printing 9 times because I have 9 subclassed buttons. hehe. Thanks to both Gaston and Scott!

Answer (score 1):

For your buttons to change on-the fly, they would have to know that the settings have changed.  They would have to listen to a broadcast message of some sort and take some action when the settings are modified.  One way to do that might be through the NSNotificationCenter -- all your buttons when they are created could listen on the default notification center for a message, then when you note that the settings have changed you could broadcast a message.

As for your code above, note that you are setting the border color in the `init` method.  That method is called exactly once, when the button is created.  That explains why your button's border colors don't change... their color is established when they are created.

Finally, it may be of interest to you (if you don't know about it) to learn more about `[UIAppearance][1]` and the way it allows you to affect the colors and styles of entire groups of controls at once.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Scott! Are there other methods I'd be able to use? like awakeFromNib?

Comment: awakeFromNib is called on objects after they have been "reconstituted" from a nib file... again only when they are first created.  You want your buttons to update on-the-fly so they are going to have to take an active interest in their own destiny while the app is running.

Comment: Is it necessary to removeObserver in a deinit? This is for ios 9+ Do I need to add 'deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }' ?

Comment: @joe Yes, you should.  But I think you added your comment to the wrong answer :-)

Comment: Whoops! sorry about that, heh. I blame a weak batch of coffee :-) Thanks for your help!